# Как разложить массив на строки и выложить каждое значение в отдельный input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, массивы

Есть 3 матрицы.Произведение матриц А и В должно выводиться в матрицу С. Вопрос как разделить данные массива и выводить каждое значение по отдельности в  input?
я так понимаю нужен цикл в котором будет разделение значений и вывод в необходимое место. Пока стоит вывод произведения только в консоль.

Я так понимаю самый простой способ разложить массив это через foreach?но он вроде как не работает в ie8.

Ниже, первая функция считывает значения из input-ов матриц А и В а еще ниже функция которая перемножает их.
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vGPEde полный код.

```
function readMatrixFromDom(aClassName) {
      var result = [];
      var rows = $('.' + aClassName).find('tr');
      for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        result.push([]);
        var cells = $(rows[i]).find('td > input');
        for (var j = 0; j < cells.length; j++) {
          result[i].push(+$(cells[j]).val());
        }
      }
      return result;
    }

  function MultiplyMatrix(A,B){

    var A = readMatrixFromDom('matrix_a');
    var B = readMatrixFromDom('matrix_b');
    var c_mat = readMatrixFromDom('matrix_c');
    var rowsA = A.length, colsA = A[0].length,
        rowsB = B.length, colsB = B[0].length,
        C = [];
    if (colsA != rowsB) return false;
    for (var i = 0; i < rowsA; i++) C[i] = [];
    for (var k = 0; k < colsB; k++){
      for (var i = 0; i < rowsA; i++){
        var t = 0;
        for (var j = 0; j < rowsB; j++) t += A[i][j]*B[j][k];
         C[i][k] = t;
      }
    }
    console.log(C);


    });

    return C;
}




$(document).on('click', '.umn' , function () {
               MultiplyMatrix();
               });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так, продолжим (отдаю должное Вашему упорству :) ).

```
function writeMatrixToDom(aMatrix, aClassName) {
  console.log("Result matrix: ");
  console.log(aMatrix);
  console.log("Result class: " + aClassName);

  var rows = $('.' + aClassName).find('tr');
  var rowCount = Math.min(rows.length, aMatrix.length);
  for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
    var cells = $(rows[i]).find('td > input');
    var cellCount = Math.min(cells.length, aMatrix[i].length);
    for (var j = 0; j < cellCount; j++) {
      $(cells[j]).val(aMatrix[i][j]);
    }
  }
}

function MultiplyMatrix(A, B) {
  var rowsA = A.length, colsA = A[0].length,
      rowsB = B.length, colsB = B[0].length,
      C = [];
  if (colsA != rowsB) 
    return C;
  for (var i = 0; i < rowsA; i++) 
    C[i] = [];
  for (var k = 0; k < colsB; k++) {
    for (var i = 0; i < rowsA; i++) {
      var t = 0;
      for (var j = 0; j < rowsB; j++) 
        t += A[i][j] * B[j][k];
       C[i][k] = t;
    }
  }
  console.log(C);
  return C;
}

$(document).on('click', '.umn' , function () {
  var A = readMatrixFromDom('matrix_a');
  var B = readMatrixFromDom('matrix_b');
  // проверка размерностей A и B на возможность их перемножения - добавить
  var C = MultiplyMatrix(A, B);
  // проверка размерности таблицы в matrix_c на соответствие размерности C - добавить
  writeMatrixToDom(C, 'matrix_c');
});
```

Comment: Т. е все таки foreach не самый хороший вариант?

Comment: @Drop Я не вижу принципиальной разницы в том, каким способом Вы пройдете по элементам массива. Просто с `for` можно заранее вычислить верхнюю границу, включив сюда ограничение по числу элементов `input`.

Comment: С каждым вашим ответом все больше познаю js)
Пока не понятно в косоле ругается на строчку 
  var cellCount = Math.min(cells.length. aMatrix[i].length);
Мол "Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

Comment: @Drop - пардон - там, конечно, запятая, а не точка: `cells.length,`

Comment: Кстати заметил что функция перемножения не срабатывала когда количество столбцов матрицы А не равно количеству строк матрицы В.
Теперь происходит волшебство и все офигенно выводиться в C матрицу.Но он сново почему то ругается на строчку
var rowCount = Math.min(rows.length, aMatrix.length);
Cannot read property 'length' of null

Comment: @Drop - добавьте в начале `writeMatrixToDom` вызовы `console.log` как у меня. Что выводится? Вы можете обновить код в codepen, чтобы я мог увидеть, как он работает.

Comment: Извиняюсь,не правильно описал условия при котором появляется ошибка.Она выползает когда столбцы не равны кол-ву строк.
И вот консоль

 Result matrix: 
style.js:172 null
style.js:173 Result class: matrix_c

Comment: @Drop Я указал в комментариях кода, что нужны проверки - перед умножением и перед выводом результата в DOM. Поменял `return null;` на `return C;`. Ошибки теперь не будет, но и результат мы не получим.

Comment: Я пока только свою функцию проверки А и В с добавлением класса добавил)

Comment: Все идеально работает.Огромное спасибо не думаю что я бы скоро смог бы написать данные циклы))Кстати по поводу проверки строк и столбцов по идее нужно написать функции для строк и столбцов матриц и далее условия с данными функциями.А вот код условия не как не могу продумать.Самый простой вариант проверки это при добавлении строк столбцов через переменную matrix 44 строка на кодепене.